# Issue Installing NRPE

Tags: nagios

From where can I extract the nrpe-x.x.tar.gz? This question is because I am trying to install NRPE form monitoring remote hosts and when I go to wget http://osdn.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/nagios/nrpe-2.8.tar.gz it turns out that file does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Visit that link in your browser, copy the link where it says "direct link", and download that using `wget` instead.